# PL/SQL trigger to check if if screening_start_hh24 is between plan_min_start_hh24 and plan_max_start_hh24

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

These are the 2 tables and 2 sequences I have created and inserted their values as well:

```
CREATE TABLE Screening_Plan
  (
   plan_id NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
   CONSTRAINT check_plan_id CHECK(plan_id > 0),
   movie_id NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
   plan_start_date DATE DEFAULT NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE,'MON') NOT NULL,
   plan_end_date DATE DEFAULT NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE + 6,'MON') NOT NULL,
   plan_min_start_hh24 NUMBER(2) DEFAULT 9 NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT check_plan_min_start_hh24 CHECK(plan_min_start_hh24 BETWEEN 9 AND 22),
   plan_max_start_hh24 NUMBER(2) DEFAULT 22 NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT check_plan_max_start_hh24 CHECK((plan_max_start_hh24 BETWEEN 9 AND 22) AND (plan_max_start_hh24 >=  plan_min_start_hh24)),
   plan_no_of_screenings NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT check_plan_no_of_screenings CHECK(plan_no_of_screenings >= 1),
   CONSTRAINT unique_movie_id_plan_start_date UNIQUE(movie_id,plan_start_date)
   );


   CREATE TABLE Screening
  (
   screening_id NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
   CONSTRAINT check_screening_id CHECK(screening_id > 0),
   plan_id NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT fk_plan_id FOREIGN KEY(plan_id) REFERENCES Screening_Plan(plan_id),
   theatre_id NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
   screening_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NOT NULL,
   screening_start_hh24 NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT check_start_hh24 CHECK(screening_start_hh24 BETWEEN 9 AND 22),
   screening_start_mm60 NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT check_start_mm60 CHECK(screening_start_mm60 BETWEEN 0 AND 59),
   CONSTRAINT unique_theatre_id_screening_date_screening_start_hh24_screening_start_mm60 UNIQUE(theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
  );

CREATE SEQUENCE screening_plan_seq 
START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 1 
NOCACHE NOCYCLE;

CREATE SEQUENCE screening_seq 
START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 1 
NOCACHE NOCYCLE;

INSERT INTO Screening_Plan (plan_id,movie_id,plan_start_date,plan_end_date,plan_min_start_hh24,plan_max_start_hh24,plan_no_of_screenings)
VALUES (screening_plan_seq.NEXTVAL,1,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),TO_DATE('08/10/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),9,17,6);
INSERT INTO Screening_Plan (plan_id,movie_id,plan_start_date,plan_end_date,plan_min_start_hh24,plan_max_start_hh24,plan_no_of_screenings)
VALUES (screening_plan_seq.NEXTVAL,2,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),TO_DATE('08/10/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),9,17,5);
INSERT INTO Screening_Plan (plan_id,movie_id,plan_start_date,plan_end_date,plan_min_start_hh24,plan_max_start_hh24,plan_no_of_screenings)
VALUES (screening_plan_seq.NEXTVAL,3,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),TO_DATE('08/10/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),9,21,4);
INSERT INTO Screening_Plan (plan_id,movie_id,plan_start_date,plan_end_date,plan_min_start_hh24,plan_max_start_hh24,plan_no_of_screenings)
VALUES (screening_plan_seq.NEXTVAL,4,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),TO_DATE('08/10/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),9,21,4);

INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,1,3,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),9,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,1,3,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),11,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,1,3,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),13,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,1,2,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),13,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,1,3,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),15,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,1,3,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),17,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,2,1,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),9,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,2,1,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),12,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,2,1,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),15,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,2,2,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),9,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,2,2,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),15,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,3,4,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),9,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,3,4,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),12,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,3,4,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),15,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,3,4,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),18,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,4,1,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),18,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,4,2,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),18,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,4,3,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),19,0);
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,4,4,TO_DATE('11/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),21,0);
```

Then I have got the following assignment question:

**Create TR_validate_screening_time trigger which fires before inserting a row in the Screening table. The trigger should check if screening_start_hh24 is between plan_min_start_hh24 and plan_max_start_hh24. If not, the trigger should raise an application error with a meaningful message.
[Note: screening_start_hh24 is in Screening table and plan_min_start_hh24, plan_min_start_hh24 are in Screening_Plan table]**

This is my trigger logic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_validate_screening_time 
BEFORE INSERT
ON Screening 
FOR 
EACH ROW
DECLARE 
v_screening_start_hh24 Screening.screening_start_hh24%TYPE;
v_plan_min_start_hh24 Screening_Plan.plan_min_start_hh24%TYPE;
v_plan_max_start_hh24 Screening_Plan.plan_max_start_hh24%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT screening_start_hh24 INTO v_screening_start_hh24 
FROM Screening 
WHERE screening_id = :NEW.screening_id;
SELECT plan_min_start_hh24,plan_max_start_hh24 INTO v_plan_min_start_hh24,v_plan_max_start_hh24
FROM Screening_Plan
WHERE plan_id = :NEW.plan_id;
IF (v_screening_start_hh24 < v_plan_min_start_hh24) OR (v_screening_start_hh24 > v_plan_max_start_hh24)
THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Screening start time should be between planned minimum start hour and planned maximum start hour');
END IF;
END;
```

The trigger has been compiled successfully as shown below:

```
Trigger TR_VALIDATE_SCREENING_TIME compiled
```

In order to make sure that the trigger runs successfully, I tried it by entering an invalid value for screening_start_hh24 column:

```
INSERT INTO Screening (screening_id,plan_id,theatre_id,screening_date,screening_start_hh24,screening_start_mm60)
VALUES (screening_seq.NEXTVAL,1,1,TO_DATE('12/9/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),8,0);
```

Then I got the following message:

```
Error report -
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "SCM_JC450912.TR_VALIDATE_SCREENING_TIME", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCM_JC450912.TR_VALIDATE_SCREENING_TIME'
```

The problem is that I am getting the error message displayed as **ORA-01403: no data found**. But I want the error message to be displayed as **ORA-20001: Screening start time should be between planned minimum start hour and planned maximum start hour**

Where did I make the mistake in my trigger code ?

It would be very helpful if the solution code is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
SELECT screening_start_hh24 INTO v_screening_start_hh24 
FROM Screening 
WHERE screening_id = :NEW.screening_id;
```

is wrong and will result in NO_DATA_FOUND because the new row isn't there yet!

Luckily all you really need is:

```
v_screening_start_hh24 := :new.screening_start_hh24;
```

Comment: Now it works ... Really appreciate for identifying my mistake.